# XMLHTTPRequest Loading

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2010, xmlhttprequest

I am struggling with loading in text from a simple text file using XMLHTTPRequest API.

Here is a list of technologies I am using in my development:

- Microsoft Visual Studios 2010
- Microsoft Internet Explorer 8

Overview:
I am running a simple index.htm page that calls a script via an input type of 'Button'. The API is allocated a reference in memory from the JavaScript and the function 'onReadyStateChange' is executed when the API state changes.

A ready state of 1 (loading) was return and no status was returned. No more instances of this function was called indicating to me that the state did not change there after.

Hint:
I am tempted to think it is something to do with the resource's location and the application running in the localhost mode apposed to on a registered website, but I just don't know.

HTML Code:

```
<body>
<input type="button" id="getSome"  title="Andrew Graham" value="Bob" onclick="Get_ListTextFile();"/>

<script src="Scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var request= new XMLHttpRequest();

function Get_ListTextFile() {


    var uniformResourceLocator = 'Bob.txt';

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest = true) {

        request.open('GET', uniformResourceLocator,true);
        request.onReadyStateChange = ServerResponse();
        request.send();

    }

}

function ServerResponse() {

    var response;

    if (request != 'undifined') {

        if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){

            response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

        }

    }

}
```

Webpage Request:
http://*ls:1920/index.htm

*ls = localhost

Contents of File:

Bob 1
Bob 2 
Bob 3

Comment: Can you try running Fiddler to see what the server response is?  The response code might tell you something useful.  IE8 Debugger doesn't do network monitoring like other browsers so fiddler is a good tool if you don't have it.    " resource's location and the application running in the localhost mode apposed to on a registered website"  - maybe you're thinking of cross-site scripting protection?  Domains need to be the same, nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You on ready state change function should be in lowercase:

```
request.onreadystatechange = ServerResponse();
```

Here is an updated version which is a little more reusable:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

function load(url, callback) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest = true) {
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
                callback(request.responseText);
            }
        }
        request.send();
    }
}

load('/', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p6H2r/

Comment: console.log will error in IE8 unless the debugger is running.

Comment: Okay, I could not see the 'wood through the trees'!

Comment: The real problem lay in the case sensitivity of JavaScript that I did not stop to consider.